# Umbraco Accelerator successfully deployed but wont connect

Tags: web-services, azure, umbraco, azure-sql-database, accelerator

I have download the umbraco accelerator to try get an azure based CMS up and running, I have managed to change the configuration file and the command prompt log upon running the .bat files does not generate any errors.

I have created the storage and azure database and hosted service but when I look at the hosted service there is no way for me to connect into this as the connect button has been disabled. Has anyone else went through the setup and if so have you encoutnered this issue? The URL displayed in azure http://appname.cloudapp.net/umbraco/default.aspx does not work

Answer (score 0):

Which Umbraco version are you deploying? AFAIK the accelerator is deprecated, but I could be wrong if you're doing something in particular, or something I haven't heard of (could be lots!) with web/hosted services.

I've deployed Umbraco 4-6 CMS through WebMatrix 2-3 to azure as a website with relative ease. I didn't need it to be a hosted service/cloudapp.

Is that url not a generic placeholder, do you have a Domain registered to point at it?

Y'know, the more I type, the more I realise I have only a shaky grasp of what you're talking about. Are you sure you need a cloudapp, will an azure website not do?